# How can I override the function in SUBclass that overrides the SUPERclass in turn (Python)?

Tags: python, super, overwrite

I need to override the SubClass1 that has already overridden the SuperClass before. It looks something like that:

```
class SuperClass:

    def function(self, args: List[str] = None):
    # some code


class SubClass1(SuperClass):

    @overrides(SuperClass)
    def function(self, args: List[str] = None):
    # some code
    super().function(args)


class SubClass2(SubClass2):

    @classmethod
    @overrides(SubClass2)
    def function(self, args: List[str] = None):
    # some code
    super().function(args)
```

There is only one difference between the function in the SuperClass1 and the SuperClass2. It's the absence of one command. I don't change any parameters.

I'm not sure that it's possible to override functions in this way. However, I have a problem only on the last step where I invoke  `super()` in the `SubClass2`

```
>       super().function(args)
E       TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Probably, I make a stupid mistake initially because in my case I have to use `@classmethod` in the `SubClass2`, and my IDE tells me about using `cls` instead of  `self` in this function.

`overrides` function:

```
def overrides(interface_class):
    """Marks method as override of parent class' method"""

    def overrider(method):
        assert (method.__name__ in dir(interface_class))
        return method

    return overrider
```

Comment: Where does the `overrides` decorator come from? Also your indentation seems wrong - please give a [mre]. And it would be helpful to explain why you're trying to override an _instance_ method with a _class_ method.

Comment: Perhaps `overrides` is the part of `pytests` so I don't use the import. Did I understand you correctly about the `overrides` decorator? I'm not sure that my indentation is wrong at all because it works.

What about `minimal reproducible example` I'm not sure that I can put here the more informative example because this code has a lot of dependencies and it has quite tricky logic. However, I hope I've shown the main scheme how it works.

Comment: I suspect my mistake is it: `you're trying to override an instance method with a class method.` As you said.

Comment: Well it's certainly not a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) like `classmethod`, and I don't see it in [the pytest API](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html?highlight=overrides) either. If you can't give people something that lets them recreate the issue, they likely won't be able to help you solve it.

Comment: I've found the `overrides` function
and yes, I import this)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because in `SubClass2` you are using the [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator, so you have to initialize a class instance before calling `super()` methods. You also have to pass the class instance a parameter, because there is no `self` in a classmethod context:

```
from typing import List

class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self, name="Name"):
        self.name = name

    def function(self, args: List[str] = None):
        print("SuperClass")
        print(self.name)

class SubClass1(SuperClass):
    def function(self, args: List[str] = None):
        print("SubClass1")
        super().function(args)

class SubClass2(SubClass1):

    @classmethod
    def function(cls, args: List[str] = None):
        new_class = cls("New Name")
        print("SubClass2")
        super().function(new_class, args)

sc = SuperClass()
sc.function()
print()
sc1 = SubClass1()
sc1.function()
print()
sc2 = SubClass2()
sc2.function()
```

I dropped the `@overrides` decorator from my example, because I think it was meaningless in this case, I assume it's [this package](https://pypi.org/project/overrides/).

Comment: Thanks for your example. But I need to override function `def function` in each class anyway because I don't want to have repeated invoke the same function. In another words, I have to get an overwritten function in each class. 
I have a working logic with two classes SuperClass and  SubClass1. I try to create new classes as I showed. I think I should give more information. I'll try to write a working example.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand what you are asking, but overwriting methods super class with method definition in subclass is not possible or in the least anything you should do.

Comment: You are right. It's not possible.
I thought that `@overrides` did something with my function, but it was like checking. (I mention it in `def overrides(interface_class):` at the end of the definition of my issue). I'll show how I solved this problem below...

Comment: And I have a mistake in my code...I didn't show that I use `function_run()` in the SuperClass. And it has anothe name. I've changed my issue

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to override the function in SUBclass. The `overrides` decorator doesn't have any sense here. I don't need to overwrite something. Instead of this, I just can direct needed class before function (I don't know why but  `super()` doesn't work in the `SubClass2`).

Here is my solution:

```py
class SuperClass:

    def function(self, args: List[str] = None):
        # some code


class SubClass1(SuperClass):

    @overrides(SuperClass)
    def function(self, args: List[str] = None):
        # some code
        super().function(args)


class SubClass2(SubClass2):

    # @classmethod // It doesn't work as I thought
    # @overrides(SubClass2) // It doesn't work as I thought
    def function(self, args: List[str] = None):
        # some code
        SuperClass.function(self, args) # For some reason, `super()` doesn't work her
```